# How to get short DOS style [ProgramFilesFolder] path in visual studio setup and deployment project?

Tags: visual-studio, path, setup-deployment

I am creating an installer for an application. In the installer (created as a Visual Studio Setup and Deployment project) I am trying to set a registry value to hold a DOS style path that includes the end-users Program Files directory... unfortunately the [ProgramFilesFolder] property provided gives me a full long style path.

i.e. I want to set a registry value that looks like this:

> C:\Progra~1\BlahBl~1\blah\

instead of this:

> C:\Program Files\BlahBlahBlah\blah

I'd rather not have to create a DLL or anything complex just to get a simple short DOS style path into the registry.

I am restricted to using a Setup and Deployment project to create this installer, I cannot use InstallShield or any other tool.